# Showing Javascript from CodeBehind Page NOT Working!

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net

I want to show a Javascript when user submit a page. I am calling this Javascript through code behind (I think this was easy). Here is my code:

```
 MessageBox1("Testing my Message"); //Calling Function!

 private void MessageBox1(string msg) //This is in the code behind of the page.
    {


        // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
        string cleanMessage = msg.Replace("'", "\\'");
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

        // Gets the executing web page
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
        if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(CommSetup), "alert", script);
        }


    }
```

This is not working...What I am doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Post the rendered javascript, as well as the server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this static method to pop the alert:

```
  public static void JS_Alert(string message)
    {
        // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
        string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

        // Gets the executing web page
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
        if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Utilities), "alert", script);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:  "Utilities" should be the name of the class you place this method in.  Mine happens to be called Utilities.  If your putting it in the code-behind partial class, its usually called whatever your web page is called with .cs on the end.

Comment: See Edit for additional info.

Comment: I did that, see my edit code. It is not showing my script...It is going inside the function but not showing script to me...

Comment: Is JavaScript enabled in your testing browser?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a Literal, use the ClientScriptManager:

```
Page.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStarupScript("startup", 
         "<script language='javascript'>window.location=''; window.alert('" + msg.Replace("'", "\\'") + "') </script>", false);
```

I forget exactly how many parameters are required, but it would look something like this.  If using a ScriptManager, there also is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "startup", ..);
```

too.

HTH.